# Sum of $k$th power of first $n$ natural number (power sum)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-series

I was working on a problem which involves computation power sum (summation of $k^{th}$ power of first natural number), can someone help me how to simplify the below equation.

I can compute power sum $n^k$ efficiently.

Below is the given equation

$$f(0,n,k)=n^k$$
$$f(m,n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^n f(m-1,i,k)$$

Problem link

[16686. Some Sums](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SOMESUMS/)

Comment: I'm sorry I clicked the problem link. The fictional scenario in which this problem comes up is beyond ludicrous.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In order to solve this problem we need some precomputation and answering every query in O(k) time or O(k log k) , So I think this summation can be reduced to some simple form of n^k.